# Issue with extracting certain OSM features using Overpass Turbo and QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, overpass-turbo

When I extract certain features from OSM using either overpass turbo or QGIS - for example: pubs, the data is either point feature (pub) or polygon (building). Showing the polygons is slightly problematic at certain scales and hard to see. Is there anyway to get round this - perhaps an improved SQL query or merge layers?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the polygons to points - either just for visualization, styling the polygons as points using `Centroid Fill`, or extracting the centroids from the polygons using `Menu Vector > Geometry Tools > Centroids...`.

*Styling a polygon layer with `Centroid Fill` in layer styling:*

[image]

Comment: Thank you - will give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider creating centroids from the polygon layer - first select those that do not have any pub features within the polygons (to avoid duplicates).  You probably know how to do that but if you are unsure:
[image]

Then select menu *Vector>Geometry>Centroids;*
[image]

Then append the new centroid point features to your existing point layer

Comment: Thank you - will give that a try now!